# How to sort comma-thousand separated numbers while on other locale

Tags: sort, locale, numeric-data

I have a German locale and need to sort US formatted numbers with commas as the thousands separator. Seems I don't override the locale properly?

```
sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.30
```

Example:

```
echo "-4.00\n40.00\n4,000.00"|LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort -h
-4.00
4,000.00
40.00
```

I actually don't expect it to change the order as `4,000` is the largest.

```
locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=de_DE.utf8
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Works fine for me with the same version of GNU `sort`. Is that en_US locale enabled on your system, shouldn't it be `en_US.UTF-8`? What's the output of `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 locale -k LC_NUMERIC`, `locale -a | grep en_US`?

Comment: If on Debian, you may need to run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root to enable that locale

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That was it, I did not have that locale installed. I naturally assumed it would be. Could you post your 2 comments as answer and I will accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible explanation is that that `en_US.utf8` locale is not available on your system.

You can use `locale -a` to get the list of available locales, `locale -a | grep en_US` for the list of US English ones.

If that locale was installed, `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 locale -k LC_NUMERIC` would output something like:

```
decimal_point="."
thousands_sep=","
grouping=3;3
numeric-decimal-point-wc=46
numeric-thousands-sep-wc=44
numeric-codeset="UTF-8"
```

and `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 locale thousands_sep` would output `,`.

Otherwise, you'd likely get an error about the locale not being available.

If on Debian, you can select which locales you want to enable with (as `root`):

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Please refrain from enabling all possible locales; enabling some locales like those using the BIG5, BIG5HKSCS or GB18030 character sets, would introduce some vulnerabilities on your system (those charsets have characters whose encoding contain the encoding of backtick and backslash causing all sorts of bugs some of which easily turn into vulnerabilities). Some locales have unusual sorting orders or case conversion rules that can also trip some software.

Note that `C` and `POSIX` are the only locales (they are meant to be the same) that POSIX guarantees to be found on POSIX systems.  It [requires the `thousand_sep` to be the empty string in that locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_04_01) though which means it's of no use in your case.

On GNU systems at least, while you won't have any guarantee that the `en_US.UTF-8` locale (or any other locale) is enabled, usually the source for the locale is available along with the `localedef` command to compile it, so you should be able to compile that locale in a temporary directory as a normal user. For instance, you could define a `us-sort` script as:

```
#! /bin/sh -

if l=$(locale -a | grep -ixm1 -e en_US.UTF-8 -xe en_US.utf8) && false; then
  LC_ALL=$l exec sort "$@"
else
  d=$(mktemp -d) || exit
  trap 'rm -rf -- "$d"' INT TERM HUP EXIT

  localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 -- "$d/en_US.UTF-8" &&
    LOCPATH=$d LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort "$@"
fi
```

That would compile that locale in a temporary directory when not available and run `sort` in it. That would be slow though as compiling a locale is an expensive operation.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, this works quite well for me. I'm on CentOS7.

```
[root@poligon ~]# echo -e "-4.00\n40.00\n4,000.00" |LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort -h
-4.00
40.00
4,000.00
[root@poligon ~]# 
[root@poligon ~]# sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.22
```

Comment: It also work on sort 8.25, a 2nd machine on debian unstable confirmed my problem however with 8.30

Comment: sort (GNU coreutils) 8.30 in debian works fine for me just as well.